# Facebook authentication in sencha touch 1.1

Tags: sencha-touch

I want to know how to authenticate a user via facebook in sencha touch 1.1.
Any working code will be apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Look out for Javascript authentication with Facebook - do a google search. That will anyhow work with Sencha 1.1.1.

Comment: I did'nt have tha much knowledge abiut authentication as  m new in sencha touch as well as in developement. So pls explain that.

Comment: Facebook authentication is done with javascript and if you know javascript, you can implement it. Yes, integrating with Sencha will need some knowledge - get ideas from API docs and tutorials.